# angular custom css class is not appening in view

Tags: html, css, angular, formio

I am working on angular formio, in that I am using a custom css class, name `CustomCSS` I have added the same in css file as follows

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formio-dzqzam?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**app.component.scss**

```
.CustomCSS {
    margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid rgb(1, 248, 1);
  padding: 10px;
    background-color: coral;
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.triggerRefresh = new EventEmitter();
    this.http.get('http://....')
    .subscribe(
      response  => {
        this.form = response.json();// this is my html script from DB
      },
        err => {console.error(err)}
    ); 

   }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<formio [refresh]="triggerRefresh" [form]="form" [submission]="submission" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></formio>
```

My Html `this.form` script as follows

```
{
   "components":[
      {
         "label":"City",
         "widget":"choicesjs",
         "customClass":"CustomCSS",
         "tableView":true,
         "data":{
            "values":[
               {
                  "label":"abc",
                  "value":"abc"
               ]
         },
         "selectThreshold":0.3,
         "calculateServer":false,
         "validate":{
            "required":true
         },
         "key":"city",
         "type":"select",
         "indexeddb":{
            "filter":{

            }
         },
         "input":true
      },
      {
         "type":"button",
         "label":"Submit",
         "key":"submit",
         "disableOnInvalid":true,
         "input":true,
         "tableView":false
      }
   ],
   "id":4
}
```

In my script also the css class name available but it is not appending in the view.

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: @robert I am doing

Comment: @Nitheesh I have updated

Comment: add your `CustomCSS` from `app.component.css` to `styles.css`

Comment: @robert when I keep the css in styles.css it is working fine, but how can I make the css working from `app.componenet.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to make it work from your component is to modify the style encapsulation for that component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core'; // <-- add ViewEncapsulation 

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <-- add this line
})
```

More information on [encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).

That being said.

I still recommend to use global styles and implement css selectors to target formio generated html elements like in your example:

```
#app formio .control-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add ::ng-deep in front of any css rule in angular to prevent css encupsulation
So in your case:

```
::ng-deep .CustomCSS {
...
```